# Issue in making Consumer Listener aware of seeking from beginning

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am not able to understand design of SeekAware interfaces.

I am trying to implement dynamic listeners to the new topic created from spring-kafka rest api.As of now only consumes consumer records from the time the listener started on topic but also wanted to modify offsets on start of this listener so that if want to `seekToBeginning`, my listener whenever invoked will read from start of topic.

the bits and pieces of important code are as follows

```
 @Component
public class CustomKafkaListenerRegistrar implements InitializingBean {
@Autowired
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory;

public void registerCustomKafkaListener(String name, CustomKafkaListenerProperty customKafkaListenerProperty,
                                            boolean startImmediately) {
        String listenerClass = String.join(".", CustomKafkaListenerRegistrar.class.getPackage().getName(),
                customKafkaListenerProperty.getListenerClass());
        CustomMessageListener customMessageListener =
                (CustomMessageListener) beanFactory.getBean(Class.forName(listenerClass));
        kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(
                customMessageListener.createKafkaListenerEndpoint(name, customKafkaListenerProperty.getTopic()),
                kafkaListenerContainerFactory, startImmediately);
    }
```

```
public abstract class CustomMessageListener {

    private static int NUMBER_OF_LISTENERS = 0;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    public abstract KafkaListenerEndpoint createKafkaListenerEndpoint(String name, String topic);

    protected MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> createDefaultMethodKafkaListenerEndpoint(String name,
                                                                                                   String topic) {
        MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> kafkaListenerEndpoint = new MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<>();
        kafkaListenerEndpoint.setId(getConsumerId(name));
        kafkaListenerEndpoint.setGroupId(kafkaProperties.getConsumer().getGroupId());
        kafkaListenerEndpoint.setAutoStartup(true);
        kafkaListenerEndpoint.setTopics(topic);
        kafkaListenerEndpoint.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory());
        return kafkaListenerEndpoint;
    }

    private String getConsumerId(String name) {
        if (isBlank(name)) {
            return CustomMessageListener.class.getCanonicalName() + "#" + NUMBER_OF_LISTENERS++;
        } else {
            return name;
        }
    }

    private boolean isBlank(String string) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(string)
                .map(String::isBlank)
                .orElse(true);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class MyCustomMessageListener extends CustomMessageListener {

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public KafkaListenerEndpoint createKafkaListenerEndpoint(String name, String topic) {
        MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> kafkaListenerEndpoint =
                createDefaultMethodKafkaListenerEndpoint(name, topic);
        kafkaListenerEndpoint.setBean(new MyMessageListener());
        kafkaListenerEndpoint.setMethod(MyMessageListener.class.getMethod("onMessage", ConsumerRecord.class));
        return kafkaListenerEndpoint;
    }

    @Slf4j
    private static class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener<String, String> {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
            log.info("My message listener got a new record: " + record);
            log.info("message is: "+record.toString());
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::sleep)
                    .join();
            log.info("My message listener done processing record: " + record);
        }

        @SneakyThrows
        private void sleep() {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I understood, `MyCustomMessageListener` will `implement` the interface   [ConsumerSeekAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerSeekAware.html) which in turn will provide method `seekToBeginning` will get invoked on creation and trigering of listener.

Kindly help.

Note: I am using `MessageListener<String, String>` having method `onMessage` which as per my knowledge is equivalent to working of `@KafkaListener`.Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement `MessageListener` there is no need for all the `KafkaListenerEndpoint` stuff; just create a listener container and add your listener to it.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So72546425Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So72546425Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner1(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so72546425", "foo");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner2(ContainerCreator creator) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println("Hit enter to create a container");
            System.in.read();
            MessageListenerContainer container = creator.createContainerForTopic("so72546425");
            container.start();
        };
    }

}

@Component
class ContainerCreator {

    private final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory;

    ContainerCreator(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String,String> createContainerForTopic(String topic) {
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createContainer(topic);
        container.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(new MyListener());
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("group.for." + topic);
        return container;
    }

}

class MyListener extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware implements MessageListener<String, String> {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> data) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        System.out.println("Seeking to beginning");
        callback.seekToBeginning(assignments.keySet());
    }

}
```

Comment: By the way; you should be using a unique group.id for each container; otherwise an unnecessary rebalance will occur each time you start a new container.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge.. The only thing is can this container be created in service class for the topic name I pass from restcontroller. If you can help In that simple change, I will be more than happy to resolve it. 

Comment: Yes; see `MessageListenerContainer container = creator.createContainerForTopic("so72546425");` in the example.

Comment: Its is so amazing to see such simple solution.I have been working on it from a week but was not sure how to start for it.thanks a ton.Last question how many maximum listener should be there for each topic.can i have 100 listeners for a topic?