# Problem with ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer to control start/stop container and get all active consumer information

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

As @garry mention on [Error while implement AcknowledgingMessageListener<String, String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72526075/error-while-implement-acknowledgingmessagelistenerstring-string) , to create consumer which manual commit with ack mode MANUAL_IMMDEDIATE. I use ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer listener container and add
AcknowledgingMessageListener class to its container properties and its work. Using Create Rest Api , i can create consumer with concurrent = 6 and thats expected result for me.

But while using another Rest Api to perform start , stop , resume , pause and get all consumer information created , KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry class not found any listener that response.
That's strange for me, because while using method registerListenerContainer in kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry class to create consumer, its working fine.
After looking in kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry class, this class working in MessageListenerContainer and i thinks that the problem. I tried to cast MessageListenerContainer
to ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer but its not work.

### CODE :

CustomKafkaContainerRegistration.java

```
@Component
public class CustomKafkaContainerRegistration {

@Value("${concurrent.consumer.kafka}")
private int concurrentConsumer;

@Autowired
public CustomConsumerFactory customConsumerFactory;

public void registerCustomKafkaContainer(Request request) {
    CustomContainerProperties customContainerProperties = new CustomContainerProperties(request.getTopicName(),request.getConsumerId());
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(
            customConsumerFactory.getCustomConsumerFactory(),
            customContainerProperties.getContainerProperties());
    container.setConcurrency(concurrentConsumer);
    container.setAutoStartup(request.getConsumerActivation());
    container.getContainers();
    container.setBeanName(request.getConsumerId());
    container.start();
}
```

KafkaConsumerRegistryController.java

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/kafka/registry")
public class KafkaConsumerRegistryController {

@Autowired
private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

@Autowired
private CustomKafkaContainerRegistration customKafkaContainerRegistration;



@GetMapping
public List<KafkaConsumerResponse> getConsumerIds() {
    return kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainerIds()
            .stream()
            .map(this::createKafkaConsumerResponse)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@PostMapping(path = "/create")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void createConsumer(@RequestBody Request request) {
    customKafkaContainerRegistration.registerCustomKafkaContainer(request);
}

@PostMapping(path = "/activate")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public void activateConsumer(@RequestParam String consumerId) {
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer) kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(consumerId);
    if (Objects.isNull(listenerContainer)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Consumer with id %s is not found", consumerId));
    } else if (listenerContainer.isRunning()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Consumer with id %s is already running", consumerId));
    } else {
        log.info("Running a consumer with id " + consumerId);
        listenerContainer.start();
    }
}

@PostMapping(path = "/pause")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public void pauseConsumer(@RequestParam String consumerId) {
    MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(consumerId);
    if (Objects.isNull(listenerContainer)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Consumer with id %s is not found", consumerId));
    } else if (!listenerContainer.isRunning()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Consumer with id %s is not running", consumerId));
    } else if (listenerContainer.isContainerPaused()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Consumer with id %s is already paused", consumerId));
    } else if (listenerContainer.isPauseRequested()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Consumer with id %s is already requested to be paused", consumerId));
    } else {
        log.info("Pausing a consumer with id " + consumerId);
        listenerContainer.pause();
    }
}

@PostMapping(path = "/resume")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public void resumeConsumer(@RequestParam String consumerId) {
    MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(consumerId);
    if (Objects.isNull(listenerContainer)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Consumer with id %s is not found", consumerId));
    } else if (!listenerContainer.isRunning()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Consumer with id %s is not running", consumerId));
    } else if (!listenerContainer.isContainerPaused()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Consumer with id %s is not paused", consumerId));
    } else {
        log.info("Resuming a consumer with id " + consumerId);
        listenerContainer.resume();
    }
}

@PostMapping(path = "/deactivate")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public void deactivateConsumer(@RequestParam String consumerId) {
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer) kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(consumerId);
    if (Objects.isNull(listenerContainer)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Consumer with id %s is not found", consumerId));
    } else if (!listenerContainer.isRunning()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Consumer with id %s is already stop", consumerId));
    } else {
        log.info("Stopping a consumer with id " + consumerId);
        listenerContainer.stop();
    }
}

private KafkaConsumerResponse createKafkaConsumerResponse(String consumerId) {
    MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer =
            kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(consumerId);
    return KafkaConsumerResponse.builder()
            .consumerId(consumerId)
            .groupId(listenerContainer.getGroupId())
            .listenerId(listenerContainer.getListenerId())
            .active(listenerContainer.isRunning())
            .assignments(Optional.ofNullable(listenerContainer.getAssignedPartitions())
                    .map(topicPartitions -> topicPartitions.stream()
                            .map(this::createKafkaConsumerAssignmentResponse)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .orElse(null))
            .build();
}

private KafkaConsumerAssignmentResponse createKafkaConsumerAssignmentResponse(
        TopicPartition topicPartition) {
    return KafkaConsumerAssignmentResponse.builder()
            .topic(topicPartition.topic())
            .partition(topicPartition.partition())
            .build();
}
}
```

Full code : https://github.com/nonefornothing/DynamicKafkaConsumer/tree/java8-containerListener

[listener container in kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry empty image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj3Da.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of containers you create in `registerCustomKafkaContainer` yourself, e.g. in a simple `ConcurrentMap<?, ?>`.

i.e. provide similar functionality to that which the `KafkaListenerContainerRegistry` provides for containers created by the framework.

Currently, you are just starting them but not keeping a reference to them anywhere.

**EDIT**

```java
private final Map<String, MessageListenerContainer> registry = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void registerCustomKafkaContainer(Request request) {
    CustomContainerProperties customContainerProperties = new CustomContainerProperties(request.getTopicName(),request.getConsumerId());
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(
            customConsumerFactory.getCustomConsumerFactory(),
            customContainerProperties.getContainerProperties());
    container.setConcurrency(concurrentConsumer);
    container.setAutoStartup(request.getConsumerActivation());
    container.getContainers();
    container.setBeanName(request.getConsumerId());
    this.registry.put(request.getTopicName(), container);
    container.start();
}

public MessageListenerContainer getContainer(String topicName) {
    return this.registry.get(topicName);
}

public MessageListenerContainer remove(String topicName) {
    return this.registry.remove(topicName);
}
```

Comment: thanks @gary-russell , any snippet code for this or any reference that i can read for doing that ?

Comment: I added an example; it assumes the topic names are unique; if not, use something else for the key. Also, you should set `container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId(somethingUnique);` to avoid unnecessary rebalances if all the containers are in the same group.

Comment: i got you point @gary.
After create container, we save it in ConcurrentHashMap and if we want to do start/stop , we just call ConcurrentHashMap in Controller.
Quick question :
why we save in MessageListenerContainer form not in ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer form in ConcurrentHashMap ?

Comment: Because `stop()` and `start()` are on `Lifecycle` which is extended by `MLC` - you don't need to reference the concrete type, just the interface, which is best practice.